# ASP.NET Store Data globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

What is the best way to store a global Data table, so that anyone accessing my website can read and add to this same table?

i was thinking of using the following code:

```
Shared DT As New DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DT.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(String))
    DT.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(String))
End Sub
```

but this will add new columns each time the page is loaded....

running a SQL database will be to slow for the website i'm coding.

Comment: This site runs off a SQL database. Do you find it too slow? Facebook runs off databases, so does Amazon, Ebay etc. Are they too slow? Twitter?

Comment: i know all about the speed of a SQL server, i uses one everyday, but for this particular website i need something faster

Comment: Sql actually open a really huge available data for you website if you have too many rows in your table what you are gonna do with session or viewstates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is global, you can store it in an Application variable.

```
Application["table"] = dt;
```

You have to cast it back whn retrieving it:

```
var dt = (DataTable)Application["table"];
```

Comment: the only downside of this is that it can't be used in a shared function, so i can not do an ajax call to modify this table....

Comment: You can access application variables in shared/static functions. You will need to use `HttpContext.Current` to get a reference to the Application property though: `HttpContext.Current.Application("myVar")`

Answer (score 3):

use

**Sessions** : if data is being used for single or current user

**ViewState** : you can also use the ViewStates to store the data

For all users you can also use

**Application** : it store data through out the application life

As @Mike Brind given example you can go with these sessions and application in the same way

The basic difference is session holds data for current user where as application holds data for all users.

and For  Sessions

```
Session["table"] = dt;

DataTable dt = (DataTable) Sessions["table"];
```

Comment: can you store a data table into View state or do you have to store it as a string

Comment: Yes you can store any data in ViewState and also in session or application variable